# sepa payment wrong name

Tags: payment, sepa

unfortunately we have been victim of the fraud and processed sepa payment from UK to Denmark for the large amount of money.my question is; how likely for fraudsters's bank to check beneficiary name as it will not match to we put in payment details?

Comment: Instead of relying on the bank reversing the payment on their own because they notice that the name doesn't match, you should rather call them themselves and see if the transfer can still be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely. Sepa transfer does not need bank to verify beneficiary name. Some banks try to verify, most don't.